# MVC: How can I change a Html.Grid row's colour based on value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I was wondering how to change the colour of a row in a Html.Grid, if a 'Completed' boolean property equals true.  Here is an example grid:

```
@Html.Grid(Model.ExampleList).Columns(c =>
        {
            c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateRequested)).Named("Date Requested");
            c.For(a => a.Comment).Named("Comment");
            c.For(a => a.Completed).Named("Completed");
        })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you mean changing the background color of a given row in the grid based on a given value of a model property. If so you could use the `RowAttributes` method:

```
@Html.Grid(Model.ExampleList)
     .RowAttributes(row => new Hash(@class => row.Item.IsFoo ? "redclass" : "normalclass"))
     .Columns(c =>
     {
         ...        
     })
```

Comment: To use the embedded syntax (e.g. @Html.Grid), I had to keep .RowAttributes() on the same line as the @Html declaration, otherwise I get a 'class is a reserved word' error.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following example, assuming you have a property you wish to highlight such as:

```
public bool IsImportant { get; set; }
```

Go to your view with the grid and then add this to the end:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
           {

//all your coloumn stuff

           }).WithPaging(10).SetRowCssClasses(item => item.IsImportant ? "important" : string.Empty)
```

Then make sure you have a reference to your required style sheet and add something like:

```
tr.important {
    background-color:rgba(205, 92, 92, 0.5) !important;   //indian red with opacity set to 50%
}
```

I found that without the `!important` expression, some of my rows styles were not being overridden by my custom styling.

Hopefully this is helpful alongside Darin's answer as I was having trouble with `.RowAttributes`